# Excluding jQuery script in a responsive layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery script for a "Back to Top" button as listed below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

// hide #back-top first
$("#TopButton").hide();

// fade in #back-top
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#TopButton').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#TopButton').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('#TopButton, #logo').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
});

});
</script>
```

I have two stylesheets one for desktop and one for mobile.  I am trying to hide the back to top button when the mobile stylesheet is used as so:

```
#TopButton {
display: none;
}
```

but it still appears.  Is there anyway around this without having mess with the HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current method is having trouble because your javascript code `.fadeIn()` will override your `display: none;`

You need to set a CSS value that won't be affected by the jquery code. I'm assuming your #TopButton is absolutely positioned? If it is, try setting a property such as

```
left: -9999px;
```

That will keep it off the page, and it won't be affected at all when jQuery tries to fade it in.

Hopefully that helps you out

Comment: Absolutely!  Have to wait 4 minutes though!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to change your HTML or CSS your code could look like

```
if ($('#TopButton').css('display')!='none')
{
    // hide #back-top first
    $("#TopButton").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#TopButton').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#TopButton').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#TopButton, #logo').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });

    });
```